# Bijection for involutive maps and $\mathbb R$-subspaces given almost complex structure (anti-involutive)? Formula for conjugation?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, complex-geometry, almost-complex

I started studying the book of Daniel Huybrechts, Complex Geometry An Introduction. I tried studying [backwards](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13089/why-do-so-many-textbooks-have-so-much-technical-detail-and-so-little-enlightenme) as much as possible, but I have been stuck on the concepts of [almost complex structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_complex_structure) and [complexification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexification). I have studied several books and articles on the matter including ones by [Keith Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf), [Jordan Bell](https://individual.utoronto.ca/jordanbell/notes/complexification.pdf), [Gregory W. Moore](http://www.physics.rutgers.edu/%7Egmoore/618Spring2019/GTLect2-LinearAlgebra-2019.pdf), [Steven Roman](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387728285), [Suetin, Kostrikin and Mainin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/2881246834), [Gauthier](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319115108)

I have several questions on the concepts of almost complex structures and complexification. Here are some:

The questions (asked towards the end of this post) are related to these questions:

- [$f$ is the complexification of a map if $f$ commutes with almost complex structure and standard conjugation. What if we had anti-commutation instead?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3520787/f-is-the-complexification-of-a-map-if-f-commutes-with-almost-complex-structu)
- [Complexification of a map under nonstandard complexifications of vector spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3520648/complexification-of-a-map-under-nonstandard-complexifications-of-vector-spaces)

**Assumptions, definitions and notations**: Let $V$ be an $\mathbb R$-vector space. Define $K \in Aut_{\mathbb R} (V^2)$ as *anti-involutive* if $K^2 = -id_{V^2}$. Observe that $K$ is anti-involutive on $V^2$ if and only if $K$ is an almost complex structure on $V^2$. Let $\Gamma(V^2)$ be the $\mathbb R$-subspaces of $V^2$ that are isomorphic to $V$. Let $AI(V^2)$ and $I(V^2)$ be, respectively, the anti-involutive and involutive maps on $V^2$.

**Observations**:

1. Let $J: V^2 \to V^2$, $J(v,w):=(-w,v)$ be the canonical almost complex structure on $V^2$. It appears $\chi: V^2 \to V^2$, $\chi(v,w):=(v,-w)$ is the unique involutive $\sigma \in Aut_{\mathbb R} (V^2)$ on $V^2$ such that $\sigma$ anti-commutes with $J$ (i.e. $\sigma$ is $\mathbb C$-anti-linear with respect to $J$) and the set of fixed points of $\sigma$ is equal to $V \times 0$.

In other words: For any $\sigma \in Aut_{\mathbb R} (V^2)$, we actually have that $\sigma = \chi$ if and only if $\sigma$ satisfies

- 1.1. $\sigma \circ J = - J \circ \sigma$,
- 1.2. $\sigma \circ \sigma = id_{V^2}$
- 1.3. The set of fixed points of $\sigma$ is equal to $V \times 0$,

2. I believe [Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf)'s Theorem 4.11 without reference to complex numbers can be restated as:

> Let $V$ be $\mathbb R$-vector space. Let $J(v,w):=(-w,v)$. There exists a bijection between $\Gamma(V^2)$ and involutive $\mathbb R$-linear maps that anti-commute with $J$. $\tag{2A}$

**Questions**:

**Question 1**. Can we generalise $(2A)$, as follows, to arbitrary $\mathbb R$-linear map anti-involutive map $K$?

> Let $V$ be an $\mathbb R$-vector space. Let $K \in AI(V^2)$. There exists a bijection between $\Gamma(V^2)$ and involutive $\mathbb R$-linear maps $\sigma$ that anti-commute with $K$.

**Question 2**. If no to Question 1: what's so special about $K=J$ that works as opposed to some other $K$ that doesn't necessarily work? If yes to Question 1: I believe half of the bijection allows us to define a map $\hat \sigma: \Gamma(V^2) \times AI(V^2) \to I(V^2)$, $\hat \sigma(A,K) =: \sigma_{A,K}$, the unique element of $I(V^2)$ that anti-commutes with $K$ and has $A$ equal to the set of its fixed points. What's the formula for $\sigma_{A,K}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following answer is based on [Joppy](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/431940)'s answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3559659).

---

Answer to Question 1. Yes, assuming axiom of choice.

- A1. Given a $\sigma$, we get $A_{\sigma}$ as follows: Actually, any $\sigma \in I(V^2)$, whether or not $\sigma$ anti-commutes with $K$ is such that $fixed(\sigma) \bigoplus fixed(-\sigma) = V^2$, where $fixed(\cdot)$ denotes the set of the fixed points (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_structure)). Choose $A_{\sigma} = fixed(\sigma)$.
- A2. Given an $A$, we get a $\sigma_A$ as follows: See answer to Question 2.
- A3. We must show that for $\gamma(A)=\sigma_A$ and $\delta(\sigma)=A_{\sigma}$, we have that $\gamma \circ \delta(\sigma)=\sigma_{A_{\sigma}}=\sigma$ and $\delta \circ \gamma(A)=A_{\sigma_{A}}=A$.
- A3.1. For $\delta \circ \gamma(A)=A$: $A_{\sigma_{A}} := fixed(\sigma_{A})$ and then by definition of $\sigma_{A}$, $fixed(\sigma_{A})=A$.
- A3.2. For $\gamma \circ \delta(\sigma)=\sigma$: $\sigma_{A_{\sigma}}$ is the unique element $\eta \in End_{\mathbb R}(V^2)$ such that $\eta = id_{A_{\sigma}}$ on $A_{\sigma}$ and such that $\eta=-id_{K(A_{\sigma})}$ on $K(A_{\sigma})$. Let's show that $\sigma \in End_{\mathbb R}(V^2)$ satisfies this property: Let $v \in A_{\sigma} = fixed(\sigma)$.
- A3.2.1. $\sigma = id_{A_{\sigma}}$ on $A_{\sigma}$: $\sigma(v)=v=id_{A_{\sigma}}(v)$
- A3.2.1. $\sigma=-id_{K(A_{\sigma})}$ on $K(A_{\sigma})$: (I am using the fact that $K$ is injective) $\sigma(K(v)) = -K(\sigma(v))=-K(v)$

Answer to Question 2. For any such $A$,

- Step 1. First, note that axiom of choice gives us $A \bigoplus K(A) = V^2$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3518285/infinite-dimensional-vector-space-has-almost-complex-structure-if-and-only-if-it); I actually can't think of a way to prove this without axiom of choice and without deducing some $\sigma$ from $A$ and $K$, the latter of which is circular).
- Step 2. By Step 1, it makes sense to say that there exists unique $\eta \in End_{\mathbb R}(V^2)$ such that $\eta = id_A$ on $A$ and such that $\eta=-id_{K(A)}$ on $K(A)$. This $\eta$ is uniquely given by the formula $\eta(a \oplus K(b))=a \oplus K(-b)$
- Step 3. Choose $\sigma = \sigma_{A,K} := \eta$: We can see that $\sigma$ anti-commutes with $K$, is involutive and has $A$ as its fixed points.