# If subspace $A$ is the fixed points of an involution $\sigma$, then is $K(A)$ the fixed points of $-\sigma$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, complex-geometry, almost-complex

I started studying the book of Daniel Huybrechts, Complex Geometry An Introduction. I tried studying [backwards](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13089/why-do-so-many-textbooks-have-so-much-technical-detail-and-so-little-enlightenme) as much as possible, but I have been stuck on the concepts of [almost complex structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_complex_structure) and [complexification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexification). I have studied several books and articles on the matter including ones by [Keith Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf), [Jordan Bell](https://individual.utoronto.ca/jordanbell/notes/complexification.pdf), [Gregory W. Moore](http://www.physics.rutgers.edu/~gmoore/618Spring2019/GTLect2-LinearAlgebra-2019.pdf), [Steven Roman](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387728285), [Suetin, Kostrikin and Mainin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/2881246834), [Gauthier](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319115108)

I have several questions on the concepts of almost complex structures and complexification. Here is one:

**Assumptions, definitions and notations**: Let $V$ be an $\mathbb R$-vector space. Define $K \in Aut_{\mathbb R} (V^2)$ as *anti-involutive* if $K^2 = -id_{V^2}$. Observe that $K$ is anti-involutive on $V^2$ if and only if $K$ is an almost complex structure on $V^2$. Let $\Gamma(V^2)$ be the $\mathbb R$-subspaces of $V^2$ that are isomorphic to $V$. Let $AI(V^2)$ and $I(V^2)$ be, respectively, the anti-involutive and involutive maps on $V^2$. Let $A \in \Gamma(V^2)$ and $K \in AI(V^2)$.

**Note**: My question as follows is related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3537869/bijection-for-involutive-maps-and-mathbb-r-subspaces-given-almost-complex-str), which asks if there exists a unique $\sigma \in I(V^2)$ that both anti-commutes with $K$ and has $A$ as equal to the set of its fixed points.

**Question**: If there exists such a $\sigma \in I(V^2)$, then is $K(A)$ equal to the fixed points of $-\sigma$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Proof:

1. Observe that $K(fixed(\eta)) \subseteq fixed(-\eta)$ for both $\eta=\pm \sigma$.

   - 1.1. For $\eta=\sigma$, $K(A) \subseteq fixed(-\sigma)$.
   - 1.2. For $\eta=-\sigma$, $K(fixed(-\sigma)) \subseteq A$.
2. Apply $K$ to latter set equality to get $fixed(-\sigma) \subseteq K(A)$.

---

Note: I hopefully do not assume either that $fixed(\sigma) \cong fixed(-\sigma)$ or that $fixed(\sigma) \bigoplus fixed(-\sigma)=V^2$.