# If propositions $P$ and $Q$ are equivalent and $P \implies R$ without using $Q$ is possible, then $Q \implies R$ without using $P$ is possible?

Tags: logic, proof-theory

Kind of a weird question. If propositions $P$ and $Q$ are equivalent and if we can show that, for some other proposition $R$, $P \implies R$ without using $Q$, then is there a proof of $Q \implies R$ that doesn't use $P$?

My thought is that if every proof of $Q \implies R$ ends up using $P$, then maybe $P$ and $Q$ are not equivalent after all.

Context: Part III here: [Finding an almost complex structure (aka anti-involution) given an involution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3559473/finding-an-almost-complex-structure-aka-anti-involution-given-an-involution)

Comment: "It is possible to do without" is not the same as "It is necessary to do without"

Comment: @GrahamKemp thanks. edited post

Comment: Let $Q = \text{True }\wedge P$ and $R = \text{False } \vee P$. You: "Oh no! You can't prove $Q \implies R$ without using $P$! Obviously $Q$ is not really equivalent to $P$!". Me: "How closely have you been monitoring your medications?"

Comment: @PaulSinclair Lol ok thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. I'm glad you took it in the spirit intended.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Related? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3626912/proving-a-thorem-using-its-converse

Comment: I don't see how. Your question has nothing to do with the converse relationships. And in the other thread José is not expressing any doubts about the validity of the proof (the [Pythagorean theorem has been proved before](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/index.shtml), so there is no logical inconsistency in using this statement to prove its converse). He just considered it an interesting approach and is looking for other examples. I am certain I have seen other examples myself, but I cannot recall exactly what they were.

Comment: @PaulSinclair thanks!